# Better way to forward declare typedef'd structures in C89?

Tags: c, typedef, forward-declaration, c89

```
struct SomeStruct;
typedef struct SomeStruct SomeStruct;
```

The above works, but is there a simpler (or better) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I don't need the first line.  The second line works by itself.

Comment: Yes - that's the obvious shortening!